# Android Absolute Layout looks good on some phones but not others?

Tags: android, layout, calculator, absolute

I made a calculator app for Android and used an Absolute layout to position the buttons and textview. It looks good on my dad's HTC Hero, but when I put it on my EVO everything is compressed to the upper left. I think it's because my screen resolution is bigger than my dad's, so the pixel measurements I use in my absolute layout do not scale correctly on my phone like it does on my dads because he has fewer pixels.

I think if I use a different layout like linear layout it will scale correctly on all phones of different resolutions. What layout can I use and how can I position the buttons where I want with it? With linear layout everything just stacks on top of each other and I cant figure out how to put things side by side and all over like buttons on a calculator app should be. Absolute layout was the only way I could think. Can someone maybe give me an example or show me a layout of a calculator app you made so I can see how you did it?

Answer (score 2):

`AbsoluteLayout` is not recommended.

To place elements side-by-side you can use `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"`.

To deal with scaling try to use `layout_weight` parameter. I.e. if you want to create a two button side-by-side taking a full space in width, and each button half of a total width you can do the following

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button 
         android:layout_width="0dp"    
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_weight="1" />   
    <Button 
         android:layout_width="0dp"    
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, consider using `RelativeLayout` where you can place each element relative to previously placed ones.

Comment: You are missing orientation attribute in LinearLayout tag.
:)

Answer (score 1):

STOP USING ABSOLUTE LAYOUT!!!!!

Prefer Relative or Nested Linear Layout to handle situation.
Use absolute layout only when its exactly required on a specific devices, until and unless don't go for it.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not screaming just to grab attention as absolute layout can cause disastrous situation. :)

Comment: There are some occasions where absolute layout is necessary.